# How to disable formatting equals column on other datagrid?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2015

I am developing a Windows Forms Application for lending. When I click on the datagrid1 add (green) button the equipment is added on datagrid2, but I would like that to only happen once for each item.

I am using this code to pass the line data:

```
private void DataGridEquipamento_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.RowIndex < 0)
    {
        return;
    }

    if (e.ColumnIndex == 2)
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in this.dataGridEquipamento.SelectedRows)
        {
            object[] rowData = new object[row.Cells.Count];
            for (int i = 0; i < rowData.Length; ++i)
            {
                rowData[i] = row.Cells[i].Value;
            }
            this.dataGridEmprestimo.Rows.Add(rowData);
        }
    }
}
```

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jCedC.png]

Comment: If you do not want the add to work more then once, add a bool variable "alreadyAddedStuff" that you do not display. It should propably also disable the Add button longterm.

Comment: thanks for the help but I have no idea how I can do this :P

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jCedC.png , datagrid1 left  and datagrid2 right

Comment: That does not answer my question. .NET has a half dozen frontend technologies. And each of them have 1-2 different DataGrids. Is this WIndowsForms, WPF/UWP, ASP.Net, XNA, other?

Comment: oh sorry it is windows forms application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a couple of ways to achieve what I believe you're asking for.

The first way would be to actually remove the item from the first list once it's been added to the second. This prevents the user from even attempting to add more than one, and ensures what the interface is presenting makes contextual sense.

With that said, to answer the question exactly, because you're effectively cloning the Row, you can perform a comparison to determine if it's already been added:

```
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in this.dataGridEquipamento.SelectedRows)
    {
        object[] rowData = new object[row.Cells.Count];
        for (int i = 0; i < rowData.Length; ++i)
        {
            rowData[i] = row.Cells[i].Value;
        }

        if (!this.dataGridEmprestimo.Rows.Contains(rowData))
        {
            this.dataGridEmprestimo.Rows.Add(rowData);
        }
    }
```

In terms of optimisation, you may only need to check for a single value from the Row - such as the Id - to determine if it already exists. You could write a simple method to return a count of Rows with that Id. If there are none, or if the number is less than the maximum allowed, then you're free to add that Row.

```
    public int CountObjectsInRows(string idValue)
    {
        int count = 0;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(idValue))
        {
            return count;
        }

        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in this.dataGridEquipamento.SelectedRows)
        {
            if (row.Cells[0].Value.ToString() == idValue)
            {
                count++;
            }
        }

        return count;
    }
```

You could use this method in place of the above "this.dataGridEmprestimo.Rows.Contains(rowData)" condition.

```
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in this.dataGridEquipamento.SelectedRows)
    {
        object[] rowData = new object[row.Cells.Count];
        for (int i = 0; i < rowData.Length; ++i)
        {
            rowData[i] = row.Cells[i].Value;
        }

        if (CountObjectsInRows(rowData.Cells[0].ToString()) == 0)
        {
            this.dataGridEmprestimo.Rows.Add(rowData);
        }
    }
```